# Definir una matriz en un modelo de datos de mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, modelos

Estoy programando un juego en javascript y tengo un escenario que es bidimensional y se guarda en una variable que es una matriz, implementada como un array de arrays que en cada posición guarda un string. Estoy creando el modelo de datos Game.js. Que recoje el estado general del juego, de tal manera que se puedan guardar las partidas en una base de datos Mongo DB.
La verdad es que no sé como declarar el dato matrix.
A continuación muestro alguna opción que estoy barajando:

**Opción A**

```
    matrix: [[{ type: String }]]
```

**Opción B**

```
   matrix:[{type: Array}]
```

**Opción C**

```
   matrix:{type: Array}
```

La que más me gusta es la opción A, porque defines el tipo del item del array, mientras que en las dos opciones siguientes no especificas si el item es un string, un número, o incluso otro array (opción C).

¿Existe al menos una forma correcta de hacer esto?

La matriz con los siguientes valores:

let matrix = [['blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'],
['blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'],
['blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'],
['blue','blue','blue','brown','brown','brown','brown','blue','blue','blue'],
['blue','blue','blue','brown','brown','brown','brown','blue','blue','blue'],
['blue','blue','blue','brown','brown','brown','yellow','blue','blue','blue'],
['blue','blue','blue','brown','brown','brown','brown','blue','blue','blue'],
['blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'],
['blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'],
['blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue']]

se vería así en secuencia, porque la matriz va cambiando de valores (al principio hay 2 posiciones verdes estáticas y una que va cambiando de lugar en amarillo y luego queda sola la de amarillo entre posiciones marrones):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo creo que la opcion A sería la correcta, pues en la B no especificas el array interno que contiene, y en la C no especificas el array de que es... en la A si especificas que es un array y dentro tiene otro array conformado por strings.

Comment: Hola, podrías añadir un ejemplo para tenerlo mas claro. gracias

Comment: @planta4, he añadido información que describe la variable matrix.

Comment: Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones, todas las opciones que muestras son correctas y a ti te gusta más la primera. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas. Por otro lado, estás usando Mongoose, con lo cual incluso puedes crear tu propio tipo de dato. Al final, cuando esto se almacene en MongoDB se convertirá en un simple Array, por más definiciones, validaciones o tipos personalizados que diseñes en Mongoose. Saludos